# How can I count the number of times a field occurred with spring elasticsearch?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm running a cronjob that runs every X minutes to find out what the most popular tags are (hashtags). I'm storing user activities in **Elasticsearch** with **Fluentd**, so say a user searches for a term, that would be stored in elasticsearch like so:

```
{ activity: "search", user: X, searchTerm: "XYZ"}
```

I've got one an activity for ***tags***. Each time a user searches for a tag, it gets inserted as an ***activity***. This way I can find out what tags a user likes as well as find out the most popular tags overall.

Here is the structure of my ES:

```
{
    "_index":"user_activity",
    "_type":"user_activity",
    "_id":"AVcokbsXKR86Bn8FzoFU",
    "_score":1.0,
    "_source":{
        "user":{
            "userId":4,
            "name":"Another one",
        },
        "activity":"CREATE",
        "date":1473854418419,
        "article":{
            {user who posted article...}
            ... Article data (title, etc...)
            // Tags associated to this article
             "tags":[
                {
                    "tagId":23,
                    "tagName":"randomTagName"
                }
            ],
         },
    }
},
{
    "_index":"user_activity",
    "_type":"user_activity",
    "_id":"AVcomLEnKR86Bn8FzoFu",
    "_score":1.0,
    "_source":{
        "user":{
            "userId":1,
            "name":"MEATTTT DAMOENNNN",
        },
        "activity":"TAG_SEARCH",
        "date":1473854873951,
        "tag":"photos"
    }
}
... There can be different types of activities
```

As you can see there are different **activity** types. I'm trying to query ES and have it return the total amount of searches for each unique tag. If you look at the **TAG_SEARCH** object, you can see it has a field **tag**. I'm trying to find the total amount of **TAG_SEARCH** activities for the unique tag value!

Here is what I've tried using the `NativeSearchQueryBuilder`.

```
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withQuery(matchAllQuery())
                .withSearchType(COUNT)
                .withIndices("user_activity").withTypes("user_activity")
                .addAggregation(terms("activity").field("activity"))
```

What this does is return the total amount of documents for each unique **activity** value. So the result for the above JSON would be:

```
"buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "create",
        "doc_count" : 1
      }, {
        "key" : "tag_search",
        "doc_count" : 1
      }
 ]
```

But what I'm trying to get is:

```
"buckets" : [ {
            "key" : "tag",
            "value": "TagNameGoesHere",
            "doc_count" : 4
          }, {
            "key" : "tag",
            "value": "AnotherTagNameGoesHere",
            "doc_count" : 10
          }
     ]
```

How can I find out the total number of unique **tag: X** values where the **activity: TAG_SEARCH**?

I'd expect the SearchQuery to look something like this:

```
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                    .withQuery(matchAllQuery())
                    .withSearchType(COUNT)
                    .withIndices("user_activity").withTypes("user_activity")
                    .addAggregation(terms("activity").value("TAG_SEARCH"))
                    .addAggregation(terms("tag")) // Count no docs per tag
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need a query on the `activity` field and then an aggregation on the `tag` field.

```
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
        .withQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("activity", "TAG_SEARCH"))
        .withSearchType(COUNT)
        .withIndices("user_activity")
        .withTypes("user_activity")
        .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("tags").field("tag"));
```

The corresponding raw JSON query would be this one

```
POST user_activity/user_activity/_search?search_type=count
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "activity": "TAG_SEARCH"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "tags": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "tag"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahh perfect. I'm pretty new to ES and having to implement it with this Java api is difficult